# Parallelism structure about gerund and noun

Tags: parallelism

is it correct to say:
lack of understanding and knowledge
because of "and" here which both sides should be parallel. left hand side we have a gerund and right hand side there is a simple noun. is this correct?
thank you in advance.

Comment: It's fine. "Understanding" is a noun (or more precisely a 'gerundial noun'). Gerunds are verbs that happen to behave like nouns.

Comment: thanks alot for your quick comment.

Comment: In the *exact* cited context, there's probably no obvious ***-ing*** form gerund to use instead of ***knowledge***. But in contexts like *I do cooking and cleaning* or *I cook and clean*, we'd nearly always use parallel constructions. We tend to avoid *I do cooking and clean* or *I cook and do cleaning.*

Comment: thanks alot for the answer. i really appreciate it.